# Latex error with simplest possible lyx document

Tags: pdf, lyx

I've used lyx successfully to publish two books. But now, starting a new project after Ubuntu upgrade to 14.04. it is giving me grief.

My plan is to use memoir. Speced it in Document Settings Document Class. When I went to view my input in PDF I got an error:

```
LaTex Error: Command\footruleskip already defined.
```

So... I closed lyx, opened a fresh new instance, and entered the simplest possible document I could imagine:

The quick brown fox

..then selected View [PDF ...] and got the same error:

> LaTex Error: Command\footruleskip already defined.

Note that this is with 100% default settings. I looked in LaTex source, but could not see the command referenced.

Can anyone tell me what I, or my lyx installation, are doing wrong and how to fix it?

Comment: I'm encountering the same problem.

Comment: Out of expediency, I switched to KOMA Script book. No problems then.